# Can anyone explain the following vim command?

Tags: vim

This is the texts that in one text file

```
1
    a
2
    b
3
    c
4
    d
```

if we `:g/ /m$`, we will reformat the text as blow.

```
1
2
3
4
    a
    b
    c
    d
```

Can anybody explain what this command did step by step? Thank you.

I interpreted as move the whitespace to the end of the line, still, I'm confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `:global/ /` goes through all lines that contain a space character (i.e. match `/ /`), and executes (from first to last matching line) the following command on it.

`:move $` moves the current line to the address `$`, i.e. the last line.

So in your example, this matches all indented lines (with letters), from `a` to `d`, and moves them, one by one, to the end.

You'll find more information on each command by invoking the built-in `:help` on it, e.g. `:help :g`

Comment: I did not know what `m$` meant, but now I do, thanks.